# Crossrider: how to collect post with nodejs and php

Tags: php, node.js, post, curl, crossrider

How do I collect a crossrider post with node js or php.

Here is the post:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
// Posting data using a JSON object
appAPI.request.post({
    url: 'http://example.com',
    // Data to post
    postData: {hello:123, name:'john'},
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        alert("Succeeded in posting data");
        alert(response);
    },
    onFailure: function(httpCode) {
        alert('Failed to retrieve content. (HTTP Code:' + httpCode + ')');
    },
    additionalRequestHeaders: {
        myHeader: 'value'
    },
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

How do I retrieve this using nodejs?
Also do I just use a normal

```
 $var = $_post
```

in php or do i have to use Curl? If I can use the above  syntax how do I specify what the POST is called? with a form I'd just use $_post["formName"] but because this is not a form what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
var data1 = "Mydata1";
var data2 = "Mydata2";
appAPI.browserAction.onClick(function() {   
    appAPI.request.post({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/Ext.php',
        postData: 'data1='+ data1 +'&data2='+ data2,
        onSuccess: function(response) {
            alert("Succeeded in posting data");
            //alert(response);
        },
        onFailure: function(httpCode) {
            alert('in posting data. (HTTP Code:' + httpCode + ')');
        },
        additionalRequestHeaders: {
            myHeader: 'value'
        },
        // contentType: 'application/json'
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
}); });
```

Then, in the Ext.php file grab the post data using $_POST["data1"] and $_POST["data2"]

Sample code for $_POST[]:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just do print_r($_POST); and you will see the variables that your server got.

You will be able to look on the response via console.log(response); or check the network tab of the chrome background page, the calls are going to the server throw there.

**Correction**:
Now i see the request on the developer tools for the page, not the extension's background page. Its easier to debug this.